End of file expected.jsonc
Visual Studio Code в файле settings.json не даёт менять настройки, пишет:

Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again.

Показывает ошибку в последней скобке и пишет:

End of file expected.jsonc

Подскажите пожалуйста решение. Ниже код:
{
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Bluloco Dark",
    {
        "workbench.colorTheme": "Bluloco Dark",
        "window.zoomLevel": 6,
        "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
        "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
        "[python]": {
          "editor.formatOnType": true
        },
        "workbench.layoutControl.enabled": false, 
        "editor.fontSize": 20,
        "editor.letterSpacing": 0.5,
        "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 18,
        "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
        "editor.hover.delay": 1500,
        "editor.glyphMargin": false,
        "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
            "statusBar.border": "#206486",
            "panel.border": "#59ace2",
        },
        "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
            "variables": "#F4F4E0",
            "textMateRules": [
              {
                "scope": [
                  "source",
                  "variable",
                  "constant",
                  "variable.other.constant",
                  "punctuation.definition.constant",
                  "constant.other.symbol",
                  "constant.language.symbol",
                  "support.constant",
                  "support.variable.magic.python",
                  "variable.other.enummember"
                ],
                "settings": {
                  "foreground": "#F4F4E0"
                }
              }
            ]
        },
      }
    
   
}


Теперь внимательно смотрите на ваш JSON. Где начало, где конец, все ли нормально с ним, свойства не повторяются?
